# Zbar Scanner Error java.lang.RuntimeException: cancelAutoFocus failed

Tags: java, android, xml, barcode, zbar

my app contains barcode scanner, i used Zbar scanner and it worked but the following error keeps appearing and I searched alot I didn't find any solution 
the error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cancelAutoFocus failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: cancelAutoFocus failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.native_cancelAutoFocus(Native Method)
```

the code I used:

```
private void initScanner(){
mScannerView = new ZBarScannerView(this);
scannView.addView(mScannerView);
mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
mScannerView.startCamera();
mScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
mScannerView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
 mScannerView.setContentDescription("barcode scanner ");
 //scanResult.setText("scan barcode automatically");
 mScannerView.setClickable(true);
```

}

```
    @Override
public void handleResult(me.dm7.barcodescanner.zbar.Result rawResult) {
    nameOfInputItems.requestFocus();
    ToneGenerator tg = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);
    tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP);
    //  nameOfInputItems.requestFocus();

    if (rawResult != null) {
        if (rawResult.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            scanResult.setText(rawResult.getContents());
            barCode=scanResult.getText().toString();

         }
  }        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

}
```

Comment: Plz try by updating your library

Comment: @ShaluTD how !? I think I'm using the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem in the code 
I should remove mScannerView.startCamera() from  onResume method